# Jquery autocomplete UL List not being populated

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have the autocomplte call data from a table, as in here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

I followed the code, and in the console, I can see the results being returned.  However, the dropdown never shows, and looking at the source, the ul `<ul id="ui-id-2" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></ul>` is never being populated with list items.

This is what the response in the console looks like:

`["Bethany University","College of the Canyons","Grand Canyon University","Bais Binyomin Academy","Albany
 Technical College","Albany State University","Bethany Theological Seminary","Saint Anthony College of
 Nursing","Bethany College","Barrett and Company School of Hair Design","Allegany College of Maryland"
,"Bethany Lutheran College","Rainy River Community College","Farmington Missouri Hospital Company","JFK
 Medical Center Muhlenberg Harold B. and Dorothy A. Snyder School of Nursing","Albany College of Pharmacy"
,"Albany Law School","Albany Medical College","Brittany Beauty School","SUNY Broome Community College"
,"CUNY School of Law at Queens College","SUNY Downstate Medical Center","Maria College of Albany","Nyack
 College","Sage College of Albany","SUNY College of Technology at Alfred","SUNY College of Technology
 at Canton","SUNY College of Technology at Delhi","SUNY College of Agriculture and Technology at Cobleskill"
,"SUNY Farmingdale","SUNY College of Agriculture & Technology at Morrisville","SUNY at Albany","SUNY
 at Binghamton","SUNY at Buffalo","SUNY Stony Brook","SUNY College of Environmental Science and Forestry"
,"SUNY Polytechnic Institute","SUNY College at Brockport","SUNY Buffalo State","SUNY College at Cortland"
,"SUNY at Fredonia","SUNY College at Geneseo","SUNY College at New Paltz","SUNY Oneonta","SUNY College
 at Oswego","SUNY Potsdam","SUNY Purchase","SUNY College of Optometry","SUNY College at Old Westbury"
,"SUNY College at Plattsburgh","SUNY Empire State College","SUNY Maritime College","SUNY Upstate Medical
 University","Allegheny Wesleyan College","Kenyon College","Community College of Allegheny County","Allegheny
 College","Gaither and Company Beauty College","Jenny Lea Academy of Cosmetology","St. Anthony Hospitals
 - Centura Health","Wilkes-Barre General Hospital\/Wilkes-Barre Hospital Company, LLC","Santiago Canyon
 College","Turner Job Corps Center - Albany","Steuben-Allegany BOCES","Cattaraugus-Allegany-Erie-Wyoming
 BOCES Olean Center","JFK Medical Center Muhlenberg Harold B. and Dorothy A. Snyder School","Central
 Coast Adult School - California Men's Colony","Sunnyvale - Cupertino Adult & Community Education","New
 World Symphony","Center for Montessori Teacher Education NY","SUNY -  Educational Opportunity Center"
,"Video Symphony Enter Training, Inc.","Sunnyside Beauty Academy","VA NY Harbor Healthcare System - Manhattan"
,"Allegheny General Hospital","The Language Company","G. V. (Sonny) Montgomery Veterans Affairs Medical
 Center","St. Anthony Hospital","Blue Sky Associates of Western NY Dale Carnegie Training","Bethany Village
 Retirement Center","Gwendolyn & Company d\/b\/a The Salon Professional Academy of Elgin","Cattaraugus-Allegany-Erie-Wyoming
 BOCES Belmont Center","Cattaraugus-Allegany-Erie-Wyoming Ellicottville Center","VA NY Harbor Healthcare
 System - Brooklyn","SUNY Buffalo School of Dental Medicine","The Academy of Cosmetology & Esthetics
, NYC LLC","Lawrence & Company College of Cosmetology","Lawrence & Company College of Cosmetology - Selma"
,"Bethany Global University","Albany Stratton VA Medical Center","Discovery Diving Company","Dale Carnegie
 Center of Excellence - NYC\/Westchester","Kenny?s Academy of Barbering","Christina and Company Education
 Center","Kenny?s Beauty Academy, Inc.","Cattaraugus-Allegany-Erie-Wyoming Olean Center","Harmony Health
 Care Institute","Hunter College - CUNY","York College - CUNY","English Language and Culture Institute-Albany"
,"Open Hearts Language Academy - NYC","The ESL School at NYFA","The ESL School at NYFA, New York","The
 ESL School at NYFA, South Beach","Johnny Matthew?s Hairdressing Training School","Karunya Institute
 Of Technology ( Deemed University)","Al-Birony University","Dunya Institute of Higher Education","Universit
\u00e9 Julius Nyerere Kankan","D\u00e1niel Berzsenyi Teacher Training College","Kodolanyi Janos University
 College","P\u00e1zm\u00e1ny P\u00e9ter Catholic University","S\u00e9chenyi Istv\u00e1n University","Universitas
 17 Agustus 1945 Banyuwangi","China Medical University Shenyang","Shenyang Institute of Chemical Technology"
,"Shenyang Jianzhu University","Shenyang Pharmaceutical University","Shenyang Polytechnic University"
,"Shenyang University","International University in Germany","Universitat Internacional de Catalunya"
,"Universitat Oberta de Catalunya","Sanyo Gakuen University","Jomo Kenyatta University of Agriculture
 and Technology","Kenya College of Accountancy","Kenya Medical Training College","Kenya Methodist University"
,"Kenyatta University","Mount Kenya University","Multimedia University of Kenya","South Eastern Kenya
 University","Technical University of Kenya","Hanyang University","Konyang University","Technological
 University (Monywa)","Ebonyi State University","University \"Transilvany\" of Brasov","Linguistic University
 of Nizhny Novgorod","Nizhny Novgorod State Academy of Medicine","Nizhny Novgorod State Architectural
 - Building University","Nizhny Novgorod State Technical University","Nizhny Novgorod State University"
,"Smolny University","Nanyang Technological University","Mwalimu Nyerere Memorial Academy"]`

Is this somehow formatted wrong?  I know that if we simple do a non callback list, it is formatted the above.  I have another input that goes that route, and it functions perfectly fine.

Here's the js:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#select-college-input" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/colleges.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( data );
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
        });
    } );
</script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="select-college-input" placeholder="University or College">
```

php:

```
    $q = $_REQUEST['q']; 
    $query = 'SELECT [ID], [Name] FROM [dbo].[Colleges] WHERE [Name] LIKE \'%'.$q.'%\'';
    $results = runQuery($connection, $query);

    $json = array();

    while($row = odbc_fetch_array( $results)) {
        array_push($json, $row['Name']);
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server returns a json **STRING** which will be interpreted by the jQuery plugin [as URL](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

The plug-in expects the result to be an array

just convert the server response to the array before you pass it to the plug-in success function

**Solution 1** (converting the response data to array at the client side)

replace this line

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( data );
}
```

with this

```
success: function( data ) {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    }catch(e){}
    response( data );
}
```

**Solution 2** (give the client a hint that the response is a JSON so the browser may convert it for you )

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

IMO I prefer doing both things because your application might involve other types of clients in the future, and you can't depend on the client(browser) to parse the JSON

Comment: @yondaimehokage Hmmm. can you please tell me what `console.log(data);` tells you when put at the first line of the AJAX success function.

Comment: I added a console.log but no console.log result shows up in the window.  I even tried a `console.log('hi');` and it doesn't appear either.

Comment: @yondaimehokage, Well then your request didn't success , add to your ajax object the error handler `error:function (j,t,e){console.log(t)}`

Comment: here is the t and e: parsererror
/impact-stats/ (line 240)
Error: jQuery112409064559469471668_1500652717805 was not called
 

...h;while(g--)d=J(a,f[g]),a[d]=!(c[d]=f[g])}):function(a){return e(a,0,c)}):e}},ps...

Comment: @yondaimehokage Do you need JSONP ? are you sending that request to a different domain? if not , then remove `dataType: "jsonp",` from the AJAX object and see what happens

Comment: Hurrah, removing jsonp plus the other changes you mentioned above work.  Thank you!

Comment: @yondaimehokage LOL, congratulation :D, , the problem was that the PHP is not responding with a JSONP, it was responding with JSON